# Build relay queries dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I´m using Relay Modern as my client GraphQL interface. I wish to know if is possible to build my query statement dynamically inside Relay Modern, something like changing that original:

```
const ComponentQuery = graphql`
    query ComponentQuery ($companyId: ID!) {
        viewer {
            company(id: $companyId) {
                id
                name
                enabled
                users {
                    id
                    username
                    email
                    firstName
                    lastName
                    jobTitle
                    phone
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

To the following:

```
let queryFields = ['name', 'enabled'];
let userFields = ['username', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'jobTitle', 'phone' ];


const ComponentQuery = graphql`
    query ComponentQuery ($companyId: ID!) {
        viewer {
            company(id: $companyId) {
                id
                queryFields
                name
                enabled
                users {
                    id
                    userFields
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Naturally, as the GraphQL Schema is static, the fields must all be present in the GraphQL schema. All I want is to build the query dynamically, not having a dynamic GraphQL schema.

Answer (score 3):

Though it's not possible to craft queries dynamically in an unbounded way as you have sketched out in your second example, you can use the `@include` and `@skip` directives to make a fixed number of choices.

### At the fragment level:

```graphql
query ComponentQuery(
  $companyId: ID!,
  $showUserDetails: Boolean!,
) {
  viewer {
    company(id: $companyId) {
      id
      name
      enabled
      users {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        ... on User @include(if: $showUserDetails) {
          email
          jobTitle
          phone
          username
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### At the field level:

```graphql
query ComponentQuery(
  $companyId: ID!,
  $showUserContactDetails: Boolean!,
  $showUserRealName: Boolean!,
  $showUserRole: Boolean!,
  $showUserUnixname: Boolean!,
) {
  viewer {
    company(id: $companyId) {
      id
      name
      enabled
      users {
        id
        firstName @include(if: $showUserRealName)
        lastName @include(if: $showUserRealName)
        username @include(if: $showUserUnixname)
        email @include(if: $showUserContactDetails)
        jobTitle @include(if: $showUserRole)
        phone @include(if: $showUserContactDetails)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All your queries and mutations in Relay need to be statically available for the compiler to generate the runtime artifacts. Any dynamic behavior needs to be controlled by graphql variables and fragments. Make sure you look through the graphql spec well.

For your case above a fragment would serve you well. The fragment can even be defined in a different file. I will give an example where you define a child component called UserComponent that will be responsible for displaying user info and a fragment that specifies what fields are required. You can then use the fragment in the parent component query. Assuming you are using react and your user type is called User.

```
/UserComponent.js
...
const UserComponent = ({ user }) => {...};
...
export default createFragmentContainer(
  ChildComponent,
  graphql`
    fragment UserComponent_user on User {
      id
      username
      email
      firstName
      lastName
      jobTitle
      phone
    }
  `
);

/Component.js
const ComponentQuery = graphql`
query ComponentQuery ($companyId: ID!) {
  viewer {
    company(id: $companyId) {
      id
      name
      enabled
      users {
        ...UserComponent_user
      }
    }
  }
}`;
```

Every time you need to render the UserComponent make sure you include that fragment in some top level query.